# Firebase and Unity: Unable to find command line tool error

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication, command-line, missing-features

After following tutorials on how to correctly install firebase into unity for an authentication system, I encountered an error that was:

Unable to find command line tool C:\The E-Learning System\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py required for Firebase Android resource generation.

From understnading it can not find either the google services file I imported into the assets folder or it could not find the generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py file. I looked online for people with similar problems could not find a clear answer to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tool that ships with the SDK to support debugging your game in the Unity Editor. One minor caveat is that an exe actually ships on Windows (I assume that this is your operating system from the C:/). You should make sure that `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe` exists in that same directory (`.exe`'s are typically ignored in many standard `.gitignore` as a catchall for build files). If it's missing, you can simply re-add the Firebase SDK and double check that this file gets included in your source repository.

If both `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py` and `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe` exist under `Assets/Firebase/Editor`, you may also want to install [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) (especially if you're still running Windows 7 or 8). This is due to a recent patch ([as of 6.10.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#version_6100_-_january_30_2020)) that fixes some incompatibilities with `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe` and older Windows variants. If that doesn't help, it would be awesome if you could [file an issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) or [reach out to support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support). If there's a bug in that fallback, it would be helpful to surface that ASAP.

Let me know if that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: I did a full reinstall but I didn't connect the IOS this time and only used android. It seemed to have worked but not entirely sure why. I am using windows 10, with the file on my C: drive, the file does show this time which I think that might have been the issue

Comment: It's super common for .exe's to be excluded in most version control systems in an effort to prevent build files from getting committed. This seems super common among perforce users, but I've seen plenty of `.gitignore` files exclude .exe's, .so's, and .a's. This is something to look out for, especially if you don't often check out on new computers or spin up new team members.